# There is any relation between "I'm fired" and "I'm on fire"?

Tags: etymology

I'm not english native speaker, and joking with a collague in my work we start a wordgame between "You are on fire?" "No, I'm fired".

Because I'm spanish bachelor I want to know if there is any ethimologic relation between these both phrases? In a complex grammar I could think that "fired" was an old verb for a common sustantive (like a participium in latin)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Etymologically (to answer OP's specific question), ***all*** senses of ***fire*** as both a noun and a verb (phrasal or not) are ***etymologically*** related to the same base noun meaning *the natural agency or active principle operative in combustion*. This is General Reference.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers! Could you write it as answer please?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've closevoted as General Reference. I don't think this is a suitable question for "answering" on ELU.

Comment: Oh! Ok, sorry. So I'll delete it

Comment: I doubt you can delete it, since two people *have* answered. Which just goes to show not everyone here thinks the same as me. But if nothing else, at least you now know of [*etymonline*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fire), which may be useful for next time. And perhaps future visitors might also benefit by knowing about that site.

Comment: Well, even there was people upvoting a not related answer :D np, thanks Fumble!

Comment: By the way, I've the same CV as you :D

Comment: On the plus side, your question seems quite clear to me (it's about *etymology*, not the *meanings*). That "clarity, specificity" aspect of questions is always welcome here (and sadly, often lacking), so please don't be put off by the fact that I CV'd it. Also, as you're not a native speaker, don't ignore the possibility of asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (but this particular question would still be GR there, I think).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm logging right now! I was mean by CV as Curriculum Vitae, because you have the same degree as me and both are actually working in software development :D

Comment: I think it's always useful on *language* sites like ELU and ELL to include nationality and native language in your site profile. And I know we probably shouldn't, but I'm inclined to take posters a bit more seriously if I see they're educated to degree level (sometimes that also helps us decide what level of complexity is suitable for an answer, or how best to phrase a comment asking for clarification, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it generally clear that a more in depth etymological account would be in order to really answer the OP's question properly ..

Comment: @Araucaria: The *etymology* is the same for all senses, so I take it you mean we should try to explain how the figurative *fire = sack, dismiss* sense arose. OED lists sense 8 *To drive (any one) away from a place by fire* as "obsolete". Under sense 16 *U.S. slang. To turn (any one) out of a place; to eject or expel forcibly; to dismiss or discharge peremptorily* they say "It has been suggested that this sense is derived from 8, but this seems unlikely". If even OED can't explain that connection in detail, I kinda doubt ELU can. It'd prolly just be opinions (for the opinionated to vote on! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That would be a good answer! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: I'm not even sure if that's the exact point OP was asking about. I don't really see how the fact of *discharge* covering both *fire a weapon* and *relieve from duty* helps "explain" anything in respect of ***fire*** having a similar spread of meanings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think he's asking broadly about the etymology of "fired" in the "you're fired" sense -  not necessarily just about if they're from the same root or not. It's unclear intuitively why we use that word in that way. This is illustrated by the interesting (to me anyway) - though probably mythological - torching  people off land theory being the closest the OED seems to have got ... which you uncovered. And would be exactly why I would delve into ELU on a Saturday eve after a nice pint at the pub!:) I'll have told about ten people that isn't where *fired* comes from by next week! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fire) indicates *fire* as a verb meaning termination to be indicative of "discharge" root meaning. From there, it's not difficult to go backwards to see fire as a noun pointing to fire as a verb applicable to weapon discharge.

Comment: And thanks for the link!!! I didn't know it, really useful

Answer (score 3):

When applied to a person, *fired* normally has just one meaning: being terminated from your job. [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fire) has this to say:

> The sense of "sack, dismiss from employment" is recorded by 1885 (with out; 1887 alone) in American English. This probably is a play on the two meanings of *discharge* (v.): "to dismiss from a position," and "to *fire* a gun," influenced by the earlier general sense "throw (someone) out" of some place (1871).

*on fire* can be applied to almost anything, and it means that it's burning.

*on fire* can also be used idiomatically regarding a person, to mean that they're really excited or doing exceptionally well. For instance, an athlete on a winning streak might be said to be *on fire*. Etymonline doesn't explain this sense, it just seems to me to be a metaphor based on how someone might run around excitedly if they were literally on fire.

Comment: Please read my question. This is not what I'm asking. I'm looking for an etymologic relation, not the meaning difference.

Comment: I doubt the "hot" athlete on a winning streak ever had any direct relationship to "running around excitedly as if they were literally on fire". It seems more like further indirection from *hot = passionate, inspired*, whence also ***hot** topics*, etc.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be several metaphoric steps.